# What is a convenient way of writing a multiline commit message?

Tags: git, terminal, git-commit

Rather than write a short, 40-character Git commit message, I would like to write a longer, multiline message.

As I understand it, I'd need to add a newline after the message 'title'. How can I enter a newline in OS X Terminal or in Win8 CMD?

Comment: *Rather than have a small 40 character git message I would like to have a full message.* Your question is unclear. I'm guessing that you use `git commit -m "..."` to create a commit, but you want to write a multiline commit message. Correct? `git commit -m "..."`  is best reserved to short (one-line) commit messages. Why not run  `git commit` instead? Your editor will pop up and you will be able to write and format your commit message much more easily.

Comment: Where comes the 40 character limit from? There is no such limit on the commit message, no matter if you write a single line or more. Write as much as you like (even on the first line).

Comment: @axiac Limiting the first line of the commit message to *50* characters is considered good practice, though; see [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/addfb21a94fb4e6b9d07b270f7bb3748767a8f38/Documentation/SubmittingPatches#L90).

Comment: @Jubobs indeed, *50* characters is considered good practice on the source code of `git` itself. Didn't know that. It's possible that the OP's organization to consider good practice (or enforce) the length of the first line to *40* characters. I usually use around *80*-*100* characters (and consider *this* limit as good practice) but I have a big screen and I work alone on the project ;-)

Comment: @Jubobs I wasn't aware that the -m could be removed. I thought that was the standard for a commit message.

Comment: @axiac My team generally stays within the commit limit, but for larger changes or release specific commits I'd like a larger message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to think ([your follow-up comment confirms this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084198/add-a-new-line-for-a-large-git-commit?noredirect=1#comment46403435_29084198)) that

```
git commit -m "<msg>"
```

is the only way of creating a commit. The [`git-commit` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) describes the `-m` flag thus:

> `-m <msg>`, `--message=<msg>`
>   Use the given `<msg>` as the commit message. If multiple `-m` options
>   are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.

This flag allows you to write the commit message *inline*; it is convenient for short (i.e. typically one-line) commit messages, but not so much for longer ones. For multi-line commit messages, you should eschew the `-m` flag and simply run

```
git commit
```

This will cause your editor to pop up and allow you to write and format your commit message in a much more convenient fashion than at the command line.

I refer you to the [relevant section of the Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Committing-Your-Changes) for more details.

Comment: Ah fantastic. Can I change my default editor then? Vim is a bit awkward and my team have never used it?

Comment: @Koxzi Yes, of course; see [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Editor). However, you should invest some time in learning Vim (or emacs); it's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't put the `-m` flag, you'll be prompted to enter the message in your default editor, where you can easily enter many lines.

Answer (score 0):

For multi line commit messages I prefer to use a file with the -F CommitMsgFile.
In the file I suggest referencing your bug/ticket thus:
CommitMsgFile:
BugName(IA-4)
Detail of what was fixed (2-3 lines).
Test notes, or link to documents/rational if exceptionally hard bug only.

result:
$git commit -F CommitMsgFile
(msg about commit)

See how it keeps the format etc in the commit message:
$git log -1
Author: name 
Date:   date info

BugName(IA-4)
Detail of what was fixed (2-3 lines).
Test notes, or link to documents/rational if exceptionally hard bug only.